# Group mysql database records by splitting into N arrays with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql database with thousands of rows, each row contains a data for a sale transaction for one of the products. These products have unique IDs and total number of products is undefined.

ID      Product Name     Transaction ID     Date

123   Product 1     ergkljdlkjfgklgh    Sept 1, 2015 
144   Product 5     eyghfeoopjfgkl    Sept 5, 2015 
123   Product 1     jdlkjfghrttgklgej    Sept 8, 2015 
144   Product 5     ngfukhjkgfhjjjcs    Sept 15, 2015 
123   Product 1     utebhjgdsdhjfdt    Sept 20, 2015 
and so on.

With help of php, I need to convert database into a simple list with each row containing unique product ID, product name, number of occurrences of that product in database, and sale dates joined into one string (that will be processed later).

To illustrate, the table above should convert into:

ID      Product Name     Number of Sales     Dates

123   Product 1     3    Sept-1-2015_Sept-8-2015_Sept-20-2015 
144   Product 5     2    Sept-5-2015_Sept-15-2015

I think the way to do it has to do with sorting and looping through different arrays, however I am a bit confused and cant quite wrap my mind around it.

Do I sort by ids, get all unique ids into array, loop through array to retrieve the groups and numbers of items, make a separate array for each group to get the dates?

Maybe someone who've encountered such challenge before can point me into the right direction :)

Comment: In a query `ORDER BY ID` - then iterate results

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create new table or work on the same one. If its a different one then its simple that you do a select using on the columns and then order them using the ID. To get the dates you can use COALESCE(field1, '_') || COALESCE(field2, ''). Else you can handle that programmatically in PHP by having a global variable that holds the value of date and then for each instance of the product append the dates using the dot operator.

Comment: Yes, I was going to make a new table with results

Comment: Then i think its fairly straight forward.

Comment: not sure what COALESCE do, there are no NULL fields in database, I was going to use php to append dates, just not sure about the arrays part

Comment: You can also do something like.. `select concat(column1,'_', column2)`

Comment: do I sort by ids, get all unique ids into array, loop through array to retrieve the groups and numbers of items, make a separate array for each group to get the dates?

Comment: you need to first decide that how you want to handle this problem. If you need programming solution then you can go with your approach (which i think is messy and might not be that efficient on the way you program it), otherwise what you can do is create a select statement that is grouped by Id and concatenates on the date columns where productId are same using join on the same table.

Comment: Are you referring to SQL statements? I am not really good with those and was hoping someone will include the complete example with their answer if that's the approach I should go with. Otherwise I was going to handle it with programming solution, that could be messy due to my limited knowledge of sql